# Create dplyr statements to later be evaluated in R

Tags: r, dplyr, rlang

I want to create a single function called `eval_data` where the user can input

1. a list of data frames
2. a list of `dplyr` functions to apply to the data frames
3. a list of columns to select from each dataframe:

This will look something like:

```
eval_data <- function(data, dplyr_logic, select_vector) {
  data %>%
    # this doesn't work
    eval(dplyr_logic) %>%
    select(
      { select_vector }
    )
}
```

The `dplyr_logic` is a list of either:

1. nothing
2. a mutate statement
3. 2 mutate statements
4. a filter

## Input 1: List of data frames:

```
dd <- list()
dd$data <- list(
  mutate0 = iris,
  mutate1 = iris,
  mutate2= iris,
  filter1 = iris
)
```

## Input 3 Select vector:

```
select_vec <- list(
  c("Species", "Sepal.Length"),
  c("Species", "New_Column1"),
  c("Species", "New_Column2", "New_Column3"),
  c("Species", "Sepal.Width")
)
```

## Input 2: list of logic to apply to each data frame in the list

```
logic <- list(
  # do nothing -- this one works
  I(),
  #mutate1
  rlang::expr(mutate(New_Column1 = case_when(
    Sepal.Length > 7 ~'Big',
    Sepal.Length > 6 ~ 'Medium',
    TRUE ~ 'Small'
    )
  )),
  #mutate2
  rlang::expr(mutate(New_Column2 = case_when(
    Sepal.Width > 3.5 ~'Big2',
    Sepal.Width > 3 ~ 'Medium2',
    TRUE ~ 'Small2'
  )) %>%
    mutate(
      New_Column3 = case_when(
        Petal.Width > 2 ~'Big3',
        Petal.Width > 1 ~ 'Medium3',
        TRUE ~ 'Small3'
      )
    )
  ),
  #filter1
  rlang::expr(filter(Sepal.Width > 3))
)

# eval_data(dd$data[[1]], logic[[1]], select_vec[[1]]) works
# eval_data(dd$data[[2]], logic[[2]], select_vec[[2]]) does not
```

## Desired Goal:

```
pmap(dd$data, logic, select_vec, ~eval_data)
```

## Desired Output

```
pmap_output <- list(
  iris1 = iris %>% I() %>% select("Species", "Sepal.Length"),

  iris2 = iris %>% 
    mutate(New_Column1 = 
             case_when(
               Sepal.Length > 7 ~'Big',
               Sepal.Length > 6 ~ 'Medium',
               TRUE ~ 'Small')) %>% 
    select("Species", "New_Column1"),

  iris4 = iris %>% 
    mutate(New_Column2 = case_when(
      Sepal.Width > 3.5 ~'Big2',
      Sepal.Width > 3 ~ 'Medium2',
      TRUE ~ 'Small2'
    )) %>%
    mutate(
      New_Column3 = case_when(
        Petal.Width > 2 ~'Big3',
        Petal.Width > 1 ~ 'Medium3',
        TRUE ~ 'Small3'
      )
    ) %>%
    select("Species", "New_Column2", "New_Column3"),

  iris3 = iris %>% filter(Sepal.Width > 3) %>% select("Species", "Sepal.Width")
)
```

What do I need to change in `eval_data` and the `logic` list in order to make this work? Any help appreciated!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two changes. First, you need to include `data %>%` into your dplyr logic evaluation:

```
eval_data <- function(data, dplyr_logic, select_vector) {
    rlang::expr( data %>% !!dplyr_logic ) %>%
        eval() %>%
        select( one_of(select_vector) )
}
```

Second, the chained mutate is actually a bit tricky. Recall that `x %>% f(y)` can be rewritten as `f(x,y)`. Your double-mutate expression can therefore be re-written as `mutate( mutate(expr1), expr2 )`. When you feed the data to it, it becomes

```
mutate(data, mutate(expr1), expr2)
```

instead of the desired

```
mutate(mutate(data, expr1), expr2)
```

So, we need to use the pronoun `.` to specify where the pipe input should go to in our complex expression:

```
logic <- rlang::exprs(                # We can use exprs instead of list(expr())
  I(),
  mutate(New_Column1 = case_when(
    Sepal.Length > 7 ~'Big',
    Sepal.Length > 6 ~ 'Medium',
    TRUE ~ 'Small'
    )),
  {mutate(., New_Column2 = case_when(       # <--- NOTE the { and the .
    Sepal.Width > 3.5 ~'Big2',
    Sepal.Width > 3 ~ 'Medium2',
    TRUE ~ 'Small2')) %>%
    mutate(
      New_Column3 = case_when(
        Petal.Width > 2 ~'Big3',
        Petal.Width > 1 ~ 'Medium3',
        TRUE ~ 'Small3'
      ))},                                  # <--- NOTE the matching }
  filter(Sepal.Width > 3)
)
```

Everything works now:

```
res <- pmap(list(dd$data, logic, select_vec), eval_data)

## Compare to desired output
map2_lgl( res, pmap_output, identical )
#  mutate0 mutate1 mutate2 filter1
#     TRUE    TRUE    TRUE    TRUE
```